# I having trouble with the dot and the bracket notation for objects in JS

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

```js
function checkObj(obj, checkProp) {

  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(checkProp)) {
    return obj.checkProp;
  }
  return 'Not Found';
}

console.log(checkObj({ gift: 'pony', pet: 'kitten', bed: 'sleigh' }, 'gift'));
```

The code above gives an output of underfined whereas it works perfectly fine if it's

```
 return obj[checkProp]
```

Why does this happen? Thanks.

Comment: `obj.checkProp` is a property with the name of `checkProp`. it does not use the variable.

Comment: There are 2 ways to retrieve properties out from an object. 1.) Dot notation 2.) Bracket notation. The 1st one cannot be used to retrieve a proerty value with a dynamic property name.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy can you elaborate on Dynamic Property name? I am new to JS so, I am not familiar with the terminology.

Comment: @Yansh Dynamic property names are nothing but names that are resolved during runtime. In other words, if you try to retrieve a value from an object with a prop (key) that was stored in a variable.